# Jquery script for submenu, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, submenu

This code works great if i want to make toggle effect by clicking on the menu. You can see the result here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu2 = $("#menu-2");
    var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function () {
        var submenu = $(this).next();
        $subs.not(submenu).hide();
        var isVisible = submenu.stop(true, true).is(':visible');
        $menu2.stop(true, true);
        if (isVisible) {
            submenu.hide(500);
            $menu2.slideUp(300);
        } else {
            $menu2.slideUp(300, function () {
                $menu2.slideDown(300);
                submenu.show(500);
            });
        }
    });
    var $subs = $links.next();
});
```

My problem is **.menu-item a**, with this the script executes the code for all links of the menu(also for links that don't have submenu links). But in my case i want to execute only for the links that contains submenu links. 
If i try t replace **.menu-item a** with **.menu > ul li a** doesn't work.

The structure of the html(generated by php) code is like this:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-1">
<li class="menu">
    <a>News</a>                                       //first main menu
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">  //second grey menu
           <li>
          <a>Mondo</a>
          <a>News Live</a>
          <a>Quotidiani Cartacei</a>

            </li>
</li>
</ul>
```

The relevant css:

```
.menu {
background-color: #F6F6EE;
border-radius: 1px;
height: 30px;
padding: 10px 10px 0 5px;
width: 100%;
}
.menu li a {
color: #716B6B;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 2px 17px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
}
#menu-2 {
background-color: #DCDCD5;
border-radius: 1px;
display: none;
height: 33px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: the fastest way is to add class to a parent li holding submenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check, on the top of the function, if the current link has a submenu attached. Check the first two lines of the `click` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu2 = $("#menu-2");
    var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function () {
        var submenu = $(this).next(".sub-menu");
        var hasSubmenu = submenu.length >= 1;

        if(hasSubmenu) {
          handleLinkWithSubmenu.call(this, submenu);
        } else {
          handleLinkWithoutSubmenu.call(this);
        }
    });
    var $subs = $links.next();

    function handleLinkWithSubmenu(submenu) {
        $subs.not(submenu).hide();
        var isVisible = submenu.stop(true, true).is(':visible');
        $menu2.stop(true, true);
        if (isVisible) {
            submenu.hide(500);
            $menu2.slideUp(300);
        } else {
            $menu2.slideUp(300, function () {
                $menu2.slideDown(300);
                submenu.show(500);
            });
        }
    }

    function handleLinkWithoutSubmenu() {
        $subs.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much. Just one question: if i want to hide the #menu-2 when i click on a link that hasn't submenu attached? I try to explain me better. If i click on "News" and #menu-2 is opened how can i tell to the script to close it #menu-2 when i click on link without submenu childs like "Politica", "Economia" or "Cronaca"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (only execute if selector has children), then replace with this:

```
 var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function (e) {
    if($links.children().length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        var submenu = $(this).next();
        $subs.not(submenu).hide();
        var isVisible = submenu.stop(true, true).is(':visible');
        $menu2.stop(true, true);
        if (isVisible) {
           submenu.hide(500);
           $menu2.slideUp(300);
        } else {
            $menu2.slideUp(300, function () {
                $menu2.slideDown(300);
                submenu.show(500);
            });
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks i undestand the idea of the control if but i have pasted it and doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will work for what you need, it's a lot cleaner and more compact:

**UPDATED:**
http://jsfiddle.net/FZHC8/2/

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .menu {
        background-color: #F6F6EE;
        border-radius: 1px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 10px 10px 0 5px;
        width: 100%;
        }
        a {
        color: #716B6B;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 2px 17px;
        width: 100%;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
        #menu-2 {
        background-color: #DCDCD5;
        border-radius: 1px;
        height: 33px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        }
        li{
        list-style:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu-menu-1">
        <li class="menu">
            <a>News</a>                                       
            <ul class="sub-menu"> 
                <li>
                    <a>Mondo</a>
                    <a>News Live</a>
                    <a>Quotidiani Cartacei</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a>News1</a>                                       
            <ul class="sub-menu"> 
                <li>
                    <a>Mondo1</a>
                    <a>News Live1</a>
                    <a>Quotidiani Cartacei1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        (function () {
            $("li > ul").hide();
            $(".menu > a").click(function (e) {
                $(this).parent().children(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);
                $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
            })
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```